# How to start sound after sound in soundmanager2

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundmanager2

How can i start sound after sound in soundmanager2, i mean when the first sound ends, second sound to start and when the second end the third start and etc and etc..

Answer (score 6):

```
var soundArray = ['sound1', 'sound2', ...];
var chain = function (sound) {
soundManager.play(sound, { 
    multiShotEvents: true,
    onfinish: function () {
        var index = soundArray.indexOf(sound);
        if (soundArray[index + 1] !== undefined) {
            chain(soundArray[index + 1]);
        }
    }});
};

chain(soundArray[0])
```

tray use recursion, the only problem can occur, when in array you put same sound twice(chain be infinity)

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of how to do this in the [documentation](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/) (see Demo 4a). The `play` method takes an object as an argument. That object contains a set of options. One of those options is an `onfinish` callback function:

```
soundManager.play('firstSound',{
    multiShotEvents: true,
    onfinish:function() {
        soundManager.play('secondSound');
    }
});
```

The `multiShotEvents` option has to be set to `true` to cause the `onfinish` event to fire upon completion of each sound. By default it will only fire once sounds have finished.

You could queue up as many sounds as you wanted to this way really.

Comment: How to do it with like 10 songs or more than 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

It took me like 3 hours to figure out.. but here it is:

```
soundManager.play('sound1',{
  multiShotEvents: true,
  onfinish:function() {
    soundManager.play('sound2',{
      multiShotEvents: true,
      onfinish:function() {
        soundManager.play('sound3');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: -1 as doesn't follow DRY principal, recursive queue function (see the [above answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10911630/1095883) for method) should be used.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ashot's answer and all the others, you can set the onfinish function when you create the sound, not only when you play it, for example:

```
var demo2Sound = soundManager.createSound({
 url: '../mpc/audio/CHINA_1.mp3',
 onfinish: function() {
   soundManager._writeDebug(this.id + ' finished playing');
 }
});
```

...and if you need to change the onfinish function once the sound is already playing, you can do so like this:

```
demo2Sound._onfinish = function(){ 
  //now this function will override the previous handler 
};
```

Comment: Good note that it belongs within `createSound()`.